# How to print the third argument received, starting from the end to the beginning Unix Korn shell

Tags: shell, unix, printing, arguments

I want to get the third argument received in a korn shell script starting from the end to the beginning.

Example:

`ksh Myscript.sh Argument1 Argument2 Argument3 Argument4 Argument5 Argument6`

It should take Argument4, just keep in mind that Arguments could changes sometimes could be 5 or 6 or even more or less...that's why I can't do it harcoded.

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate an array with all the argument in `ksh` and do this to print 3rd from last argument:

```
arr=("$@")
n=$(echo "$# - 3" | bc)
echo "${arr[n]}"
```